# How to hide this proof depending on my command's value?

Tags: macros, environments, appendix, proof-package

The following Latex code allows me to create an appendix automatically where proofs are stored by setting the value of the command `\moveToAppendix` to `1`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,USenglish]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm,amsmath}
\usepackage{thmtools, thm-restate}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\newcommand{\moveToAppendix}{1}

\newenvironment{varProof}[1]
{
    \restatable{proof}{#1}
}
{ 
    \endrestatable
}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{theorem}
        Toto.
    \end{theorem}
    
    \begin{varProof}{ProofOne}
        Tata.
    \end{varProof}
    
    
    \if\moveToAppendix1 
    \newpage
    \appendix   
    \section{Auxiliary proofs}
    
    \ProofOne
    
    \fi
    
\end{document}
```

The problem is, when `\moveToAppendix` is set to `1`, the proofs still remain in the main part of the paper (outside of the appendix), how would I go about making them invisible when the value of `\moveToAppendix` is set to `1`?

EDIT:

After a comment, I decided to include an example of what I want, but it's somewhat of a bother to define each proof like below and I was wondering whether I could define it in an environment somehow in a simpler manner to use each time I place a proof.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,USenglish]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm,amsmath}
\usepackage{thmtools, thm-restate}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\newcommand{\moveToAppendix}{0}

\newenvironment{varProof}[1]
{
    \begin{proof}{#1}
}
{ 
    \end{proof}
}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{theorem}
        Toto.
    \end{theorem}
    
    \newcommand{\ProofOne}{
        \begin{proof}
            Tata.
        \end{proof}
    }\if\moveToAppendix0\ProofOne\fi
    
    \if\moveToAppendix1 
    \newpage
    \appendix   
    \section{Auxiliary proofs}
    \label{appendix:aux}
    
    \ProofOne
    
    \fi
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just wondering: What do you think `\restable{proof}` does? To me it seems the idea with the macro is to typeset its contents and store it for later, so of course it is listed after the theorem no matter what you do in the test.

Comment: This is how I understood it as well, which is what I want EXCEPT for the fact that is listed after the theorem. I tried working with \newcommand as well to store the proof in a command, after which I can use the command to show the proof depending on my variable, but I'd have to define the command and call it every time with if statements etc. and was wondering if there was a way to put it all in an environment instead.

Comment: @daleif I added an example to my post which has the desired behaviour but now it is somewhat bothersome to write each proof like this, I'd like to know if it's possible to put this in an environment.

Comment: You should probably start by explaining exactly what your end goal is. Then perhaps others can help you (instead of providing some code that might not be the best solution)

Comment: Could you tell me what you don't understand?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `\restatable` prints the contents of the theorem where it is called.

A different approach might be to use a `\savebox` and then recall it in the appendix.

```tex
\documentclass[a4paper,USenglish]{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm,amsmath}
\usepackage{thmtools, thm-restate}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\newcommand{\moveToAppendix}{1}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{varProof}{mb}{
    \expandafter \newsavebox \csname#1box\endcsname
    \expandafter \global \expandafter \sbox \csname#1box\endcsname {%
        \parbox { \columnwidth } { 
        \begin{theorem}
            #2
        \end{theorem}
    }}
    \expandafter \gdef \csname#1\endcsname {%
        \expandafter\usebox\csname#1box\endcsname
    }
    \if\moveToAppendix0
        \noindent\csname#1\endcsname
    \fi
}{}


\begin{document}
    
    \begin{theorem}
        Toto.
    \end{theorem}
    
    \begin{varProof}{ProofOne}
        Tata.
    \end{varProof}
    
    \if\moveToAppendix1 
        \newpage
        \appendix   
        \section{Auxiliary proofs}
        \ProofOne
    \fi
    
\end{document}
```

Note however, with this approach the theorem number will be based on where `\begin{varProof}` is *called*, and not where it is eventually printed in the appendix.

**Edit:** For older (pre 2019) TeX installations, we need to use the `Environ` package.

```tex
\usepackage{environ}

\NewEnviron{varProof}[1]{
    \expandafter \newsavebox \csname#1box\endcsname
    \expandafter \global \expandafter \sbox \csname#1box\endcsname {%
        \parbox { \columnwidth } { 
        \begin{theorem}
            \BODY
        \end{theorem}
    }}
    \expandafter \gdef \csname#1\endcsname {%
        \expandafter\usebox\csname#1box\endcsname
    }
    \if\moveToAppendix0
        \noindent\csname#1\endcsname
    \fi
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't execute for me, showing among many errors that it doesn't recognize `\NewDocumentEnvironment`.

Comment: You likely have a rather old version of LaTeX then. 
You could try to add `\usepackage{xparse}` (should work for 2019 and newer)

Comment: I have also just included modifications in case your installation is older than 2019

Comment: I changed `\begin{theorem}` to `\begin{proof}` and it works when my variable is set to `1` (proof goes to appendix) but when it is set to `0` the proof doesn't show up anywhere.

Comment: Ah, yes whoops, forgot about that.
Should be fixed now

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps?

[image]

#### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{environ}

\newif\ifmoveprooftoend
\newcommand\showDeferredProofs{}

\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{movableProof}[1][Proof]{%
        \ifmoveprooftoend
                \edef\next{\noexpand\g@addto@macro\noexpand\showDeferredProofs{%
                        \noexpand\begin{proof}[#1]\unexpanded\expandafter{\BODY}\noexpand\end{proof}}}
                \next
        \else
                \begin{proof}[#1]\BODY\end{proof}
        \fi}{}
\makeatother

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\begin{document}

\begin{thm}
First theorem
\end{thm}

\begin{movableProof}
        Proof of first theorem
\end{movableProof}

\moveprooftoendtrue
\begin{movableProof}[Alternative proof of first theorem]
        Alternate proof
\end{movableProof}
\moveprooftoendfalse

\begin{thm}
        Second theorem
\end{thm}

We give the heuristics of the proof here, and defer the full proof later.
\begin{movableProof}[Heuristic argument]
        Heuristics of second theorem
\end{movableProof}

\moveprooftoendtrue
\begin{movableProof}[Actual proof of second theorem]
        Proof of second theorem
\end{movableProof}

\begin{thm}
        Really a lemma
\end{thm}

\begin{movableProof}
        Lemma's proof is still deferred
\end{movableProof}

\section{Deferred proofs}

\showDeferredProofs

\end{document}
```

#### Explanation

```
\newif\ifmoveprooftoend
\newcommand\showDeferredProofs{}
```

Since you really want a boolean toggle, might as well define it using a `\newif` instead of a `\newcommand`. This way the `\if` testing can be written a bit easier.

You can turn the toggle on with `\moveprooftoendtrue` and turn it off with `\moveprooftoendfalse`.

The creation of the `\showDeferredProofs` command is so that you can gather up all the deferred proofs and print them all at once with a single command (as opposed to your piecemeal `\ProofOne` approach.)

```
\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{movableProof}[1][Proof]{%
        \ifmoveprooftoend
                \edef\next{\noexpand\g@addto@macro\noexpand\showDeferredProofs{%
                        \noexpand\begin{proof}[#1]\unexpanded\expandafter{\BODY}\noexpand\end{proof}}}
                \next
        \else
                \begin{proof}[#1]\BODY\end{proof}
        \fi}{}
\makeatother
```

We define a new environment called `movableProof`. What it does is it tests the present value of the boolean toggle `\ifmoveprooftoend`. If it is *false* then it acts as the standard `proof` environment. If it is *true*, it appends to `\showDeferredProofs` the necessary ingredients to print the proof later.
(The trick with `\edef\next` is because we want to expand `\BODY` one level before appending it to `\showDeferredProofs`.)